# How to get individual information from owl by passing its name to a java program

Tags: java, ontology, owl

I have an owl file and I need to write a java program in which I pass the individual name (such as Lion)  and get all object/data properties values related to this individual from owl (such as: `Golden` from `has_color` object property, etc.).

I wrote a java class based on the easiest 
api `uk.ac.ebi.brain.core.Brain`, but this API doesn't have methods to list individual information.
So is there any other simple ways to fill-full my needs?

In the following example, I'm retrieving the subclasses of the main class `Animal`
and I don't know how to retrieve the individuals of each subclass or even by pass the name of individual to get the object/data properties of this individual:

```
import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.OWLIndividual;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAnonymousIndividual;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectProperty;
import uk.ac.ebi.brain.core.Brain;
import uk.ac.ebi.brain.error.BrainException;

public class AnimalIndividuals {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BrainException {
        Brain brain = new Brain();
        brain.learn("d:\\Animal.owl");
        List<String> subClasses = brain.getSubClasses("Animal", false);
        for (String subClass : subClasses) {
            System.out.println("Subclass of Animal: " + subClass);
        }
        brain.sleep();
    }    
}
```

Comment: [whathaveyoutried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). Shown us some sample code to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently (March 2013) not possible to retrieve the individuals attached to an object property using Brain because it is not yet implemented by [ELK](https://code.google.com/p/elk-reasoner/), the underlying reasoner in charge of this operation.

However, it seems to me that you can play around your modelling. You could assert `Lion` as a class 
 rather than as individual. You could further define the concept `Lion` as a subclass of `has_color some Golden`. It means in OWL that all the lions are golden, but things can be golden without necessarily being lions.

Implementation with Brain:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws BrainException {
    Brain brain = new Brain();

    //Declaration of the concepts and properties
    brain.addClass("Animal");
    brain.addClass("Lion");
    brain.addClass("Golden");
    brain.addObjectProperty("has_color");

    //Axioms assertion
    brain.subClassOf("Lion", "Animal");
    brain.subClassOf("Lion", "has_color some Golden");

    //Query
    List<String> results = brain.getSubClasses("has_color some Golden", false);
    System.out.println(results);

    brain.sleep();
}
```